# AWS CDK and caching the cdk.out directory in build pipelines

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using BitBucket pipelines to deploy an app to AWS using the Python CDK. As part of the process the cloud assembly `cdk.out` directory is created as documents in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/assets.html).

I am wondering if there is any benefit in caching this directory so that it's reused between pipeline runs, just like we cache `pip` dependencies for example, or just let it be created from scratch on every pipeline run.

Comment: Is your pipeline calling `cdk deploy`?

Comment: @fedonev yes it does

Comment: There is a benefit. It tries not to rebundle assets if the hash is the same. It depends on which hashing strategy you use. I have forced CDK to cache `cdk.out` in the past and it has helped speed up some of my pipelines. You might be able to use 2.29.0's [new pipeline caching](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/20533).

Answer (score 2):

`cdk deploy` [synthesizes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-synth) the [CloudAssembly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/apps.html#apps_cloud_assembly) artifacts into `cdk.out` each time before deploying.  Caching wouldn't help there.

However, the CDK apparently [caches zipped artifacts](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/cdk-assets/lib/private/handlers/files.ts) (before uploading to S3), so in theory you could save `.zip`-ing time by caching `cdk.out/.cache`.

Comment: Try one time to make an arbitrary deployment with `cdk deploy`. This produces assets and templates in `cdk.out` used for the deployment. Now, try successively 
- re-running `cdk deploy`.
- removing `cdk.out` and re-running `cdk deploy`

The latter takes much more time than the former, which I think invalidates your statement that caching would not help.

Comment: @EmileTenezakis Repeat deploys are faster because CDK can sometimes skip the S3 artefact upload, context lookups, and CloudFormation steps.  But it always generates new local artefacts and hashes.  The CDK re-synthesizes on each deploy to see whether there have been code/asset changes that require artefact redeploy.  Ask yourself:  how else would the CDK handle cache invalidation?